# How to sum values by grouping by account/id/category?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still beginner with JavaScript and ReactJS.

I have a list that shows some operations that the user make. What I would like to know is how to calculate the total of operations according to the account that was passed by the user, how do I group this data?

For example, if the user types for account `A` two transactions of `$5` and `$2` the total of account `A` will be `$7`. And if he types for account `B` a transaction of `$3`, the total of account `B` should be only `$3`, with the image below it is more easy to explain what i mean:

And [here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-tereshkova-m27gj?file=/src/index.js) my code.

[image]

**My ContextAPI:**

```js
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const AppContext = React.createContext();

const initialState = {
  balance: 0,
  transactions: []
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TRANSACTION":
      return {
        ...state,
        balance: state.balance + action.payload.amount,
        transactions: [
          {
            account: action.payload.account,
            amount: action.payload.amount,
            balance: state.balance + action.payload.amount
          },
          ...state.transactions
        ]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

AppContextProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};

export { AppContext, AppContextProvider };
```

**My list of transactions:**

```js
import React from "react";

import { AppContext } from "../../providers";

const List = () => {
  const { state } = React.useContext(AppContext);

  return (
    <div>
      {state.transactions.map((transaction) => (
        <div key={Math.random()} style={{ marginBottom: "10px" }}>
          <div>
            <span>
              <strong>
                {transaction.amount > 0 ? "Transferred" : "Withdrew"} $
                {Math.abs(transaction.amount)}{" "}
              </strong>{" "}
              {transaction.amount > 0 ? "to " : "from "}
              <strong>{transaction.account}</strong>.
            </span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>
              Current <strong>{transaction.account}</strong>'s balance is{" "}
              <strong>${Math.abs(transaction.balance)}</strong>.
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Thank you very much for any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to keep track of each account's balance now. so store in your state something like (eg for accounts a & b):

```
 balances: {"a": 10, "b": 20}
```

Now when you go to add a new transaction add/subtract the appropriate balance and keep track.

```
const initialState = {
  balances: {},
  transactions: []
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TRANSACTION":
      return {
        ...state,
        balances: {
          ...state.balances,
          [action.payload.account]:  (state.balances[action.payload.account] || 0) + action.payload.amount
        },
        transactions: [
          {
            account: action.payload.account,
            amount: action.payload.amount,
            balance:
              (state.balances[action.payload.account] || 0) + action.payload.amount
          },
          ...state.transactions
        ]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-herschel-4j141

Answer (score -1):

theres no sample data but it looks like you add the balance to one „account“ instead of two. consider adding A‘s value to one and B‘s value to another. Hope I could help you